# Upgrading Parse Server from v3 to v4 triggers error `GraphQL: Must provide Source`

Tags: parse-platform, graphql, apollo, parse-server

I use ParseServer (https://parseplatform.org) in version 3.10.x with the included GraphQL endpoint. I use `apollo-link` to make some queries from my cloud code and therefore having the `graphql` module installed (in addition with the dependencies of the `parse-server` that use `apollo-server`). I've specified the version of the GraphQL dependency to match the one used by `parse-server` (v14.5.8).

In this configuration everything work fine.

I now upgrade `parse-server` to the last version 4.3.x, and update `graphql` in order to continue to match the version used by the `parse-server`: v15.1.0.

The server now crash at launch with the error: `Must define Source. Received undefined.`.

- So I've try to remove the `graphql` dependency, I still get the error.
- I've downgraded `graphql` to the previous version v14.5.8 and get another error since 2 different instances of `graphql` are used.
- I checked that only one version of GraphQL is used across dependencies.

I've checked the `graphql` module loaded when the error occurs: `./node_modules/graphql` in version v15.1.0.

Does anyone have a clue on this error and the way to fix it?

If any more details required, please ask!

Thanks,

Perceval

---

**EDIT #1**

Parse Server is launched wrapped in clusters by `throng`.

***Parse Server initialization***

```
const restAPI = new ParseServer(config)
const graphQL = new ParseGraphQLServer(restAPI, {
    graphQLPath: process.env.GRAPHQL_MOUNT || "/graphql",
    playgroundPath: "/playground",
})

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use(process.env.PARSE_MOUNT, restAPI.app)
graphQL.applyGraphQL(app)
```

***Parse Server Configuration***

```
{
        appName: process.env.PARSE_APP_NAME,
        databaseURI: process.env.DATABASE_URI,
        databaseOptions: {
            maxTimeMS: Number(process.env.DB_QUERY_MAX_TIME) || 30000,
        },
        cloud: `${__dirname}${cloudCode}`,
        appId: process.env.PARSE_APP_ID,
        masterKey: process.env.PARSE_MASTER_KEY,
        clientKey: process.env.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY,
        javascriptKey: process.env.PARSE_JAVASCRIPT_KEY,
        restAPIKey: process.env.PARSE_REST_KEY,
        serverURL: serverURL,
        publicServerURL: serverURL,
        allowClientClassCreation: process.env.ALLOW_CLIENT_CLASS_CREATION === 'true',
        filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
            process.env.S3_BUCKET, {
                bucketPrefix: process.env.S3_BUCKET_PREFIX,
                directAccess: true
            }),
        verifyUserEmails: false,
        emailAdapter: MailAdapter(),
        cacheAdapter: process.env.REDIS_PARSE_CACHE_URL
            ? new RedisCacheAdapter({ url: process.env.REDIS_PARSE_CACHE_URL })
            : null,
        liveQuery: {
            classNames: ["SomeClass"],
            redisURL: process.env.REDIS_LIVE_QUERIES_SERVER_URL
        },
    }
```

***Complete error stack***

```
$ heroku local web
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
10:45:21 web.1   |  > pinpo-parse-server@4.2.9 start:dyno:web /Users/percypyan/Developer/projects/pinpo/pinpo-parse-server
10:45:21 web.1   |  > npm run start:process:${WEB_PROCESS_NAME}
10:45:22 web.1   |  > pinpo-parse-server@4.2.9 start:process:parse-server /Users/percypyan/Developer/projects/pinpo/pinpo-parse-server
10:45:22 web.1   |  > node --optimize_for_size --gc_interval=100 lib/apps/parse-server
10:45:24 web.1   |  Error: Must provide Source. Received: undefined.
10:45:24 web.1   |      at devAssert (/Users/percypyan/Developer/projects/pinpo/pinpo-parse-server/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/devAssert.js:12:11)
10:45:24 web.1   |      at new Parser (/Users/percypyan/Developer/projects/pinpo/pinpo-parse-server/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:80:67)
10:45:24 web.1   |      at Object.parse (/Users/percypyan/Developer/projects/pinpo/pinpo-parse-server/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:35:16)
10:45:24 web.1   |      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/percypyan/Developer/projects/pinpo/pinpo-parse-server/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/introspectSchema.js:39:42)
10:45:24 web.1   |      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
10:45:24 web.1   |      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
10:45:24 web.1   |      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
10:45:24 web.1   |      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
10:45:24 web.1   |      at Function.wrappedLoad [as _load] (/Users/percypyan/Developer/projects/pinpo/pinpo-parse-server/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:481:24)
10:45:24 web.1   |      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm
10:45:24 web.1   |   ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR! errno 1
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm
10:45:24 web.1   |   ERR! pinpo-parse-server@4.2.9 start:process:parse-server: `node --optimize_for_size --gc_interval=100 lib/apps/parse-server`
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR! Exit status 1
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR!
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR! Failed at the pinpo-parse-server@4.2.9 start:process:parse-server script.
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR!     /Users/percypyan/.npm/_logs/2020-09-09T08_45_24_589Z-debug.log
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm
10:45:24 web.1   |   ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR! errno 1
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm 
10:45:24 web.1   |  ERR! pinpo-parse-server@4.2.9 start:dyno:web: `npm run start:process:${WEB_PROCESS_NAME}`
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR! Exit status 1
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR! 
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm
10:45:24 web.1   |   ERR! Failed at the pinpo-parse-server@4.2.9 start:dyno:web script.
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
10:45:24 web.1   |  npm ERR!     /Users/percypyan/.npm/_logs/2020-09-09T08_45_24_655Z-debug.log
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
10:45:24 web.1   Exited with exit code null
```

Comment: could you share the command you are using to initialize Parse Server and also the complete error stack?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I completed the post with the required details! Thanks :)

Comment: When you run your sever in your local machine, do you see the same error?

Comment: Yes I do, in fact this stack trace come from my local machine.

Comment: Those logs look coming from Heroku. I mean you try to start the node.js app directly from your machine.

Comment: I've used the command `heroku local web`, that's why it looks like heroku logs. But the app is running on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some weeks without further research, I've been suggested to try with `npm` instead of `yarn`. So I've tried and the whole thing was running normally again.

The problem was in the lock file: after deleting it, even back with `yarn`, the problem was fixed.

So if you're in this situation, try to delete `node_modules` folder and lock file and then re-run `yarn` or `npm install`. This should do the trick.

Parse Community forum: https://community.parseplatform.org/t/parse-4-2-startup-error-must-provide-source-received-undefined/278/11

Thanks to Parse core contributor [davimacedo](https://community.parseplatform.org/u/davimacedo/summary) to helping me to solve that issue!